# Как сделать, чтобы в RewriteRule передавались GET параметры?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, route

У меня в .htaccess прописано следующее:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/games/([A-Za-z0-9-?._]+)$ /games/index.php?lang=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

Как мне сделать что бы можно было к url ещё дописать дополнительные параметры, но уже не через .htaccess  а прямо в адресной строке?

**Например:**

- сейчас у меня есть url вот такой: `site.ru/ru/games/starcraft`
- как мне сделать что бы прописать параметр вот так: `site.ru/ru/games/starcraft?hideblock=true`, где `hideblock` это параметр который передается `$_GET` запросом в файл `/games/index.php` ?

В **/games/index.php** пишу:

```
<?php
$hideblock = $_GET['hideblock'];
echo $hideblock;
?>
```

А в **htaccess**  пишу:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/games/([A-Za-z0-9-?._]+)?hideblock=([a-zA-Z]+)$     /games/index.php?lang=$1&name=$2&hideblock=$3 [L]
```

и ничего не работает!

Как сделать роутинг на php что бы в .htaccess  каждый параметр не писать?

**UPD:** Добавил: `[L, QSA]` сервер выдает:

> Internal Server Error

Comment: Надо пробел убрать

Answer (score 3):

За передачу query string отвечает [параметр QSA](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)

```
RewriteRule ... [L,QSA]
```

Все дополнительные параметры будут добавлены к переданной в скрипт query string.

Comment: Нужно без L, т.е. не [L, QSA], а просто [QSA]